# Cropping rectangles in python OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have the following code which  successfully finds rectangles in a chessboard and puts each contour in `valid_cnts` Numpy Array, its size is 64 (8 X 8), and each index in the array includes a different rectangle. I would like to crop each different rectangle and save them as a picture.

```
   # Find contours and find squares with contour area filtering + shape approximation
      cnts = cv2.findContours(invert, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
      r = 0
      cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
      valid_cnts = []
      v = []
      for c in cnts:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4 and area > 100 and area < 10000:
          x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
          cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), 2)
          cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)
          valid_cnts.insert(r,c)
          v.insert(r,[x,y,w,h])
          r = r + 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need something like `image[x:x+w, y:y+h]` for each (x, y, w, h) tuple describing one of  your 64 rectangles.

Comment: What does it return? an image?

Comment: I tried it, it's not accurate

Comment: `image[x:x+w, y:y+h]` is wrong, it should be `image[y:y+h, x:x+w]`

Comment: Use numpy slicing to slice a sub array from your original array.

Comment: Can you elaborate, on how would I proceed with the cropping? @stateMachine

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I know the methods, I just don't understand how they relate to cropping a certain rectangle? thanks

Comment: it seems that you don't want **cropping** because cropping implies cutting vertically/horizontally. you want a **perspective warp** because you want a straight view of a quadrilateral that's a **projection** of an actual square.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `for` loop, after the vertex and area filters you calculate the bounding rectangle of the contour like this: `x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)`. Here, you have the dimensions of the region of interest: **top left coordinate**, **width** and **height** . If you want to crop this area, use [numpy slicing](https://towardsdatascience.com/slicing-numpy-arrays-like-a-ninja-e4910670ceb0) with the bounding rect dimensions:

```
if len(approx) == 4 and area > 100 and area < 10000:

   # Get the left top corner, width and height of the contour
   # bounding rectangle:
   x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

   # Slice the area of interest from the original image:
   croppedImage = originalImage[y:y+h, x:x+w]

   # Show the crop:
   cv2.imshow("Cropped Iamge", croppedImage)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Just be careful with the order of the slicing indices: you first slice vertically and then horizontally. The first index starts at `y` and ends at `y + h`, the second index starts at `x` and ends at `x + w`.

Also, if you drew something on your original image, you probably will see the drawn info on the cropped image too. You might need to create a [deep copy](https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/) of the image using the [copy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html) method: `imageCopy = originalImage.copy()`. Create the deep copy before drawing your debugging information and use that exclusively for your slicing: `croppedImage = originalImage[y:y+h, x:x+w]`.